# Is there a difference between types: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame and <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to copy python code from one platform to another, and have had to manually reconstruct a DataFrame that features as an input, however am having errors in using the DF. When I run type() on each DF, one returns "" and the other returns "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"

What is the difference, and how can I convert one into the other?

Edit to add pictures showing the DFs and the varying responses to type() that I get:

[image: This shows the first DF]

[image: This shows the second DF]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add some sample code for this issue?

Comment: "When I run type() on each DF, one returns """ It returns an empty string? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi both - thanks for responses. I've added screenshots to shot the DFs, and the results of running type() on both of them. I can add code, however there's a lot of it, as both DFs are constructed differently - one from a series of API calls, then appended to a master DF, and the other from a function that returns the DF. The first picture above is the API + append generated one, the second is from the function. I will add all further requested details as I very much appreciate your input on this!!! Thanks again!!!!